# Image ContentScale not applied correctly when Coil's Crossfade is set to true

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I am using Coil to load a remote image in Jetpack Compose but I am facing a strange problem.

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
 Column() {

            Image(
                painter = rememberImagePainter(
                    data = recipe.featuredImage,
                    builder = {
                        crossfade(true)
                        placeholder(R.drawable.empty_plate)
                    }
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(225.dp),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                contentDescription = null
            
            ) ....}
```

When I set crossfade to `true` the image is not cropped or stretched to fit the Width. However, when the crossfade is `false` the image is properly cropped to fit the Width.

Strangely, when I scroll the image off the screen and then scroll the image back to the screen, it is properly cropped even when the Crossfade is set to `true`.
[image]

**Image A** - *Image not displayed properly*,       **Image B** - *Correct display that I need*.

I want to use crossfade because the images take a bit of time to load and I want to show the image the first time the screen loads instead of the user having to scroll down for the image to display properly.

Have looked around but can't figure out how to resolve this, any leads?

Comment: Don't set your modifier to fillMaxWidth(). Try setting it to a fixed width and see if that solves the problem. Compose perfers fixed values when it comes to loading images.

Comment: @Johann  Thanks for the suggestion, I tried setting the width to a fixed width of 300.dp but did not see any difference. This is bug on Coil as described on my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the problem I have is a [reported bug](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/855) and the extract from this reads as follows:

*... "To work around this for now, the size of the placeholder can be reduced to be less than the size of the loaded image. In the sample project, this can be done by reducing width and height of ic_food.
I tried looking into this, and it seemed to be happening because the placeholder image was bigger (and had a different aspect ratio) than the loaded image. This meant that the intrinsic size of the CrossfadePainter was based off the size of the placeholder".*

To resolve the issue I simply ***used a smaller placeholder*** in dimens (24 x 24) and left the Crossfade on, this resolved the problem.